# How can I create bullet points for my website in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble figuring out how to position items in HTML/CSS, as I'm pretty much a newb when it comes to coding. But I wanted to do this myself without paying a developer.

Basically, I want to create a 3 column width "How it works" with 3 elements(classes?) in each column. An Icon, the heading, and subheading.

It looks like this: https://www.screencast.com/t/KAKYgJQYVLS

Can someone point me in the direction of just getting the headings on top of one another and the each bullet points next to each other?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Use `<ul>` and `<li>`

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1. Heading 2 lines of text</li>
  <li>2. Heading 2 lines of text</li>
  <li>3. Heading 2 lines of text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one. If you want these bullets much bigger, you should replace these by using image or anything else.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/32/sign-check-icon.png');
}

ul li {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>1. Heading</h3> 
    two lines of text
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>2. Heading</h3> 
    two lines of text
  </li>
  <li>
     <h3>3. Heading</h3> 
     two lines of text
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you all for all the advice.How can I add images instead of bullets? I was thinking of putting icons next to each section. Also the font for the headings and text will likely be different fonts/sizes?

Comment: @johnnyjones I have updated my answer. You can check out the demo now. Hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your starting out I would take a look at a framework like Bootstrap it makes this stuff a lot easier and has good examples of how to do things.

http://getbootstrap.com/

```
<div class="container">

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
     <h3>
       heading 1
     </h3>
     <p>
     sub heading
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
   <h3>
       heading 2
     </h3>
     <p>
     sub heading
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
   <h3>
       heading 3
     </h3>
     <p>
     sub heading
     </p>
   </div>
 </div>


</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/475/

Answer (score 0):

May be you would like to tweak with below HTML and CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
.center {
    float:none;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:600px;
}
.content {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
.col-3 {
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}
.col-3 p {
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 5px;
}
.cell {
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
}
.rounded-icon {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #a84909;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="cell">
          <h3><div class="rounded-icon"></div>Heading 1</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc lectus felis, tristique...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="cell">
          <h3><div class="rounded-icon"></div>Heading 2</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc lectus felis, tristique...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="cell">
          <h3><div class="rounded-icon"></div>Heading 3</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc lectus felis, tristique...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```